# CakePHP - Adding a "back to top" button on multiple pages

Tags: html, css, cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-2.0

I have never worked with CakePHP before and need to add a button that'll take a user back to the top of a page. My question is how can this be done for multiple, but not all of pages, using the framework?

I couldn't figure it out and need a quick solution to this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think that this has no relation to the `CakePhp`! It can be ashieved using `html` and `javascript`, try this : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp

Comment: what do you mean  how can this be done for multiple, but not all of pages ?

Comment: I need a button on only some of the pages in my project, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to go about this one. Simplest is edit your default.ctp (or whichever) layout with a simple condition:

```
<?php if (!empty($backToTop)) : ?>
  <!-- html & JS back to top code here-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in the Controller Actions that you want the back to top button to display:

```
$this->set('backToTop',true);
```

If there are only a few exceptions to not having the 'back to top' script, then you may want to have the condition to exclude the code rather

Comment: The controller should not determine this pure view logic, it breaks the idea of MVC.

Comment: That's a rather rigid 'idea of MVC'... Be that as it may, there's no conflict at all with the MVC pattern itself here. The controller sets a var for the view to consume (or not). As I said, many ways to go about this one, I went for the simplest and most practical approach considering @cheesycode is new at Cake

Comment: You set a var from the controller, that is only relevant in the context of the view, as it controls something *only* relevant to the view. The controller doesn't care about it nor does it use this var at all for anything. If you want to do it this way, I would set it in the `App\View\AppView` initialize()` method but clearly not in the controller. The var can be overriden as needed inside a specific view file then as well.

Comment: Ok, I’d be interested to see your solution in practice. Why not update your answer with it? Just FYI I think cheesycoder is working with Cake2, but keen to see your 3.X solution anyway - I'll vote up your 3x answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper or a method in a generic utility helper for your app that renders the button or use an element that you can include where you need it.

If you want to call it on every page put your helper or element call in your layout file(s).

In the case you need an exception on a certain page you could put that logic in the helper method as well, or the element, and check if the request object attached to the view matches your desired controller and action.

Official Documentation:

- [Elements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements)
- [Helpers](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html)
- [Layouts](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts)